# Integer and Complex Values for the Gamma Function:

Tags: gamma-function

While reading the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function) page on *Particular values of the Gamma Function*, it listed a formula:$$\Gamma\left(\dfrac z2\right)=\sqrt{\pi}\dfrac {(z-2)!!}{2^{(z-1)/2}}\tag{1}$$
Where $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ for positive half integers. $(1)$ can be used to compute $\Gamma\left(\frac 12\right)$ by setting $z=1$ to get$$\Gamma\left(\dfrac 12\right)=\sqrt{\pi}\dfrac {(1-2)!!}{2^{(1-1)/2}}=\sqrt\pi\tag{2}$$
Extending this, I'm wondering

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. Can forumula $(1)$ be generalized to include complex numbers?$$\Gamma\left(a+bi\right)=\text{something}\tag{3}$$
> 2. If so, how would you prove such formula?

Running it for [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B1-Sqrt%5B-1%5D%5D), it says that the Gamma function of a complex number is defined and is possible. But I'm just not sure how to derive a formula for $(3)$.

Comment: complex numbers with integer $a$ and $b$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses Uh... yes. $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: not sure if this was up when the question was posted, but the Wikipedia page does have some numeric data on complex values of Gamma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_Gamma_function#Imaginary_and_complex_arguments no closed forms are given, which may have motivated the question

Answer (score 1):

There is no corresponding formula for complex values of $z$: unlike adding ordinary integers, there is no way to relate $\Gamma(a+i)$ to $\Gamma(a)$ (except that one has absolute value smaller than the other, by trivially bounding the integral definition). One can find the absolute value of $\Gamma(yi)$ for real $y$ by using the reflection formula (which comes out as $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{y\sinh{(\pi y)}}}$), but there is no equivalent to $\Gamma(1+z)=z\Gamma(z)$. 
Hence one can relate the values of $\Gamma$ along a horizontal string of points separated by integers, but there is no way to move between these.

This is, in effect, a worse version of the problem with expressing $\Gamma(1/n)$ in finite form for $n>2$: there is no nice formula containing just one of these quantities: you only have things like $$ \Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(2/3) = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{3}} $$
from the reflection formula, or
$$ \frac{\Gamma(1/3)\Gamma(5/6)}{\Gamma(2/3)} = \sqrt[3]{2}\sqrt{\pi} $$
from the duplication formula.